# Javafx setCellValueFactory : NullpointerException

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, java-8, javafx-8

Let's consider the following code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TestController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<TestRow> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TestRow, String> myColumn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        table.setEditable(true);

        myColumn.setCellValueFactory(data ->data.getValue().nameProperty());
        myColumn.setCellFactory(factory -> new TextFieldTableCell<>(new StringConverter<String>() {
            @Override public String toString(String object) {
                return object;
            }

            @Override public String fromString(String string) {
                return string;
            }
        }));
        myColumn.setPrefWidth(200);

        table.getItems().add(new TestRow("Name1"));
        table.getItems().add(new TestRow("Name2"));
    }
}
```

Sometimes I got `NullpointerException` at line `myColumn.setCellValueFactory(data->data.getValue().nameProperty());` when I want to edit the cell in the Name column and I have no idea why, I entered with debug and it says that the data.getValue() is null so then its obvious that I get `NPE` when applies `.nameProperty()`. The question is when can be null the data and why? I was trying to figure out but simply I didn't find anything. In debug I was looking for data.getTableView().getItems() and it returns the two rows those were added. Do you have any idea why is the `data.getValue()` ( which have to return an existing `TestRow` instance that the `table` contains)?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that `null` was inserted as an item to the table view. You can check every place where you add a new item to the table to see that it does not add null values. If there aren't many such places in the code you can edit your question and post all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i fixed it by always checking the null value.

My guess is that when a TableRow recieve a null value it still have to be display as a graphic component in some way and so does the Cell and the ValueFactory is call (you could want to display custom value on empty row).

Comment: But as I know is a bad practice to make null checks, I saw somwhere that if you are writing a super clean and perfect code you never need to check for null, so I also tought that this solves my problem but then I did't get the source of the `NPE` so later it may cause some unexpected bugs and then it will be much harder to detect why that bug occured.

Comment: I agree that null check are mostly proof of a bad application design and that in this case you should be able to manage empty row in another way, i just don't know any.

Comment: In this case I cannot put there a nullcheck because I work with that data that comes from cell, so if I out there anything else that is not the data that supposed to be there then I got inconsistent data.

Comment: I may have explaining wrong, you don't have inconsistent data. I'm saying that the need by JavaFX to display totally the table make him create empty row.

Comment: The table is not going to invoke the cell value factory on an empty cell. Either you have inserted a null value in the table, or `nameProperty()` is returning null.

Comment: @James_D then if I enter with debug why do it says that `data.getValue()` is null? On the UI of course there is the cell and the value, if it were not there then i couldn't click on the cell. So I have no idea why, and this information doesn't give me any suggestion about why the NPE occurs.

Comment: @Sunflame As mentioned, the most likely cause is that you are inserting null values in the table. Nothing in the code you posted would cause the behavior you observe, as far as I can tell: you need to post a [MCVE].

Comment: I cannot post the whole code for some obvious purposes but I think I have an idea why that occurred, or at least a guess( sorry I don't know the proper English word). So I think the table.refresh() caused this problem, i have a huge table with a lot of data and when I entered the cell there was a lot of validations, and I could solve them without refreshing the table, so maybe somehow this caused the NPE. After introducing your sollution for refresh in several places the NPE disappeared, even if I click the sell like a mad.